Merging class definition with generic type definition
So say there is a type or interface that defines properties of actions, for example:
export interface AnimalActions {
  jump: { height: number }
  move: { speed: number, offset: number }
}

And there is class that should implement these actions depending on the generic prop, for example:
export class AnimalAction<T extends keyof AnimalActions> {
  type: T;
  constructor(type: T, actionProps: AnimalActions[T]) {
    this.type = type;
    Object.assign(this, actionProps);
  }
}

const action = new AnimalAction('jump', { height: 10 });
action.type // "jump" 
action.height // 10, typescript error here

Playground here, see the error on the last line.
Is there some way to type AnimationAction class so it does not throw an error for height?
I realize that I can create a third type, for example:
type ExtraAnimalAction<T extends keyof AnimalActions> = AnimalAction<T> & AnimalActions[T];

const action = new AnimalAction('jump', { height: 10 }) as ExtraAnimalAction<'jump'>;
action.type // "jump" 
action.height // 10, no error

playground with no error
Is there some way to do this without adding a type?

Why do you want to create a class for this? You can also just create separate types for Jump and Move. If you  really want to force a class to implement actions, you should investigate abstract classes

There is no way to do this with class declarations, since class declarations require all keys to be known at compile time. So you need a new type. I would suggest writing it as shown in this playground so that the type assertion happens once, for the constructor, and not for every instance. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

As mentioned by @user3791775 , jcalz , classes don't really work this way, as properties by design are meant to be known, and Javscript internally doesn't understand generics.   But objects can have dynamic props, mix this with Typescript and you could do this -> https://shorturl.at/rm3VI
